# AWS CLI - SSL check on every bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm just getting started with learning AWS CLI, I was wondering is there a way of checking pre-existing buckets and seeing if they have SSL enabled?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
buckets=`aws s3api list-buckets | jq -r '.Buckets[].Name'`

for bucket in $buckets
do
    #echo "$bucket"
    if aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket $bucket --query Policy --output text &> /dev/null; then
        aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket $bucket --query Policy --output text | jq -r 'select(.Statement[].Condition.Bool."aws:SecureTransport"=="false")' | wc | awk {'print $1'}`
```